# how to detect the specific word to make it as a right answer?

Tags: python

I am making a program like a family feud where the user needs to guess a right answer according to the topic he chose. How can I get the specific word if he inputted only 1 word?

```
from nltk.corpus.reader import WordListCorpusReader
import os
again = True
print("GUESSING GAME")

print(reader.words('D:/VB/topic1.txt'))
while again:
    num = int(input("PICK A NUMBER FOR THE TOPIC [1-3]: "))
    if num == 1:
        print("1. Name something people are afraid of. ")
        print("======================================")
        print("You need to guess 10 right answers in order to win. ")
        reader = WordListCorpusReader('D:/VB/topic1.txt', ['topic1.txt'])
        for i in range(0,10):
            element = (input(str(i + 1) + ". "))
```

topic1.txt file:

Spiders

Heights

Other people

Dying

The dark

Ghosts

Snakes

The IRS

Being alone

Their boss or getting fired

---

For example, the user guessed: Dark. In my file, the answer is the "The Dark". How can I declare it as a right answer without including the "The". Another example would be "Their boss", I want to make the guess right if the user only input "Boss"

Comment: One option: make a list of common words, like articles, pronouns, demonstrative adjectives, etc. then split the answer in words, remove the common words at the beginning so a clean answer is left.

Comment: Do I just need to remove the "The" or "Their"?

Comment: Up to you: define the checking strategy that best fits your needs, the code follows.